# Difference between return ''; and return; in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to Javascript. My teammates are using `return '';` and `return;` in functions. Still, I don't know the difference between them.

Can anyone clarify the difference and the use cases?

```js
function function1() {
  return '';
}

function function2() {
  return;
}
```

Comment: First returns an empty string, second returns `undefined`

Comment: and `return 125` would be yet another thing. There's a whole world of possibilities.

Comment: return '' -> returns empty/null
return; returns undefined

Comment: there are lot of documentation/tutorials out there, please try to refer those before putting questions here.

Comment: Those single-quotes appearing pairwise really look like a single unmatched double-quote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First function returns an empty string, second returns *nothing* **ie**`undefined`.

You can try it like this:

```js
function function1() {
  return '';
}

function function2() {
  return;   
}

function function3() {
  // do some stuff   
}

console.log(function1())        //string
console.log(function2())        //undefined as it returns 'nothing'
console.log(function3())        //same output as function2()
```

**If** there were any lines written after `return` statement those would **not** execute. Because, `return` halts the execution of the current function and gives back the control to the *caller function* .

As edit suggested by [@NinaScholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz):
Note: Not returning anything is same as not writing `return` at all to the *caller* function. In both the cases it will receive `undefined` as that is the default return value (Except in the case of a constructor called with the new keyword).

For more info: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: you may mention the default return value without `return`.

Comment: Dang, I almost broke the monitor when shooed a fly on the screen ...

Comment: @NinaScholz mentioned in updated answer. Also, thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: That "default return value" of functions is not always `undefined`. There is an exception to that. But I will let you discover it . (hint: just check the MDN doc of `Functions`)

Comment: @KarelG Updated. Thanks for pointing out. :)